# Splitting a cell in pandas DataFrame and counting values

Tags: python, pandas

I have an xlsx file with survey data sorted by questions as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Question 1': ['5-6 hours', '6-7 hours', '9-10 hours'],
    'Question 2': ['Very restful', 'Somewhat restful', 'Somewhat restful'],
    'Question 3': ['[Home (dorm; apartment)]', '[Vehicle;None of the above; Other]', '[Campus;Home (dorm; apartment);Vehicle]'],
    'Question 4': ['[Family;No one; alone]', '[Classmates; students;Family;No one; alone]', '[Family]'],
})

>>> df
Question 1   Question 2        Question 3                               Question 4
5-6 hours    Very restful      [Home (dorm; apartment)]                 [Family;No one; alone]
6-7 hours    Somewhat restful  [Vehicle;None of the above; Other]       [Classmates; students;Family;No one; alone]
9-10 hours   Somewhat restful  [Campus;Home (dorm; apartment);Vehicle]  [Family]
```

For Questions 3 and 4, the input was a checkbox style, allowing for multiple answers. How could I approach getting the value counts for specific answer choices, rather than the value counts for the cell as a whole?

e.g

```
Question 4
Family                    3
No one; alone             2
Classmates; students      1
```

Currently I'm doing this:

```
files = os.listdir()
for filename in files:
    if filename.endswith(".xlsx"):
        df = pd.read_excel(filename)
        for column in df:
                x = pd.Series(df[column].values).value_counts()
                print(x)
```

However, this doesn't allow me to seperate cells that have multiple answers.
Thank you!

Comment: What is the _exact_ format of the data in pandas?  `"[Home (dorm; apartment)]"` or `["Home (dorm; apartment)"]`?

Comment: @Alexander it's in the form "[Home (dorm; apartment)]"

Comment: What is the expected output for `Question 3`?

Comment: @Alexander my goal is to return the # of instances of each answer choice, so Question 3 would look like `[Home (dorm; apartment)]   2, [Vehicle]   2, [None of the above]  1, Other  1, Campus  1`

Comment: The challenge is parsing the string.  If you used the semi-colon as the delimiter, it ends up as `['Home (dorm", " apartment)"]`.

Comment: yeah, the formatting used by the survey collector is not ideal by any means. I was curious if it was possible to assign each input to a variable and count for how often that variable occurred in a single column, like `a = '[Vehicle]'` and return `a = 2 instances`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets you part of the way, but I don't know how to parse your data.  For example, if you used the semi-colon as the delimiter in `Question 3`, the parsed string ends up as `['Home (dorm", " apartment)"]`.

```
>>> pd.Series([choice.strip() 
               for choice in df['Question 4'].str[1:-1].str.split(';').sum()]
    ).value_counts()
Family        3
alone         2
No one        2
Classmates    1
students      1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean `groupby` ? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-groupby/

`df1 = df.groupby('Question 4')`

or `groupby('...').agg(...)`

https://www.shanelynn.ie/summarising-aggregation-and-grouping-data-in-python-pandas/